# Comment prononcer le son « on » lorsqu’il est suivi d’une voyelle?

Tags: prononciation, adjectifs, liaisons

Quand les francophones disent « bon appétit » ou « bon anniversaire », j’entends « bonne » au lieu de « bon ». Par contre pour « son » dans « son anniversaire » il me parait toujours « son » et pas « sonne ». Alors y a-t-il une règle? Ce phénomène se reproduit-t-il uniquement pour le mot « bon » ou ai-je mal entendu le locuteur?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dans les phrases « en plein hiver » et « en plein air »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/dans-les-phrases-en-plein-hiver-et-en-plein-air)

Answer (score 9):

La règle est celle observée avec ***bon***. Une nasalisation finale disparaît en présence d'une liaison.

L'exception concerne les possessifs ***mon***, ***ton*** et ***son*** et le pronom ***on*** avec lesquels la nasalisation est le plus souvent maintenue malgré la liaison qui suit.

M**on a**vion est un b**on a**vion.

/m**ɔ̃n**‿aviɔ̃ ɛt‿œ̃ b**ɔn**‿aviɔ̃/

On arrive !

/**ɔ̃n**‿ariv/