# Changement de prononciation de « bon » devant « épisode »

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

Quelqu'un était en train de parler d'une série Netflix, et elle disait « un bon épisode », mais elle la prononçait « bon**NE** épisode ».

Je connais bien les adjectifs masculins qui changent devant un nom commençant par une voyelle, (*beau/bel*). Mais l'adjectif *bon* n'en fait pas partie.

Je ne trouve pas d'infos sur un changement de prononciation de *bon* et j'ai peur de me ridiculiser. Il y avait une faute dans sa prononciation ou on prononce vraiment « bonNE épisode » ?

Comment: More generally: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/dans-les-phrases-en-plein-hiver-et-en-plein-air

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est un exemple de liaison, exactement comme on fait avec *beau/bel*. Dans le cas de *bon* la consonne est déjà présente dans le mot tandis qu'il faut l'ajouter à *beau*.

Lorsque le /n/ se fait entendre, *bon enfant* se prononce de la même façon que *bonne enfant* (j'ai choisi *enfant* parce que ce mot est épicène). La voyelle n'y est plus nasalisée car le /n/ s'attache maintenant à la syllabe suivante. On dit alors /bɔnɑ̃fɑ̃/ dans les deux cas.

Answer (score 3):

Non, c'est une prononciation considérée comme correcte.

> ([dénasalisation](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/liaisons-et-enchainements)) quand la finale est une voyelle nasale, le n se fait entendre tandis que la voyelle nasale se dénasalise dans certains cas :
> bon [bɔn] appétit
> en plein [plɛn] été
> le Moyen [mwajɛn] Âge

> ([BDL](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3545)) Le son ɔ̃ (on) peut lui aussi être touché par la dénasalisation en contexte de liaison; il se prononce alors [ɔ] (o), comme dans « porte ». Cette dénasalisation se produit toujours quand l'adjectif « bon » précède un nom. Avec les déterminants « **mon** », « **ton** » et « **son** », elle est facultative. Dans les autres mots, comme dans le pronom « **on** », ce son reste nasal.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - La natation est un très bon exercice. [bɔnɛgzɛʀsis] (bo-nèg-zèr-sis)
> - J'ai perdu mon étui à lunettes. [mɔnetɥi] (mo-né-tui) ou [mɔ̃netɥi] (mon-né-tui)
> - On a pu le constater tout à l'heure. [ɔ̃napy] (on-na-pu)

You'll find [here (Kalmbach)](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/20a.html#liaison-avec-nasales) a thourough treatment of the subject of liaisons involving nasals.